# Email Regex to allow only 1 character aposthrope before @symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I modify this regex for email? Current my regex does not allow for an apostrophe:

```
"^[A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.]+[@]([A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+)+[\\.]([A-Za-z]{2,4})$";
```

Now I want add apostrophe, however the request is to only allowed 1 apostrophe before @ symbol.

I tried to use this:

```
"^([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.]+[']{0,1})+[@]([A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+)+[\\.]([A-Za-z]{2,4})$";
```

It allows apostrophe input, however I can input more than 1 apostrophe before @ symbol

Result:

`test''test@yahoo.com` -> not allowed

`test'tes't@yahoo.com` -> allowed (expected not allowed)

Expected result is that only one apostrophe is allowed before @ symbol.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: possible failure to understand email syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

here is a modified version of your regex :

```
"^([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.]*?)'?([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.]+)[@]([A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+)+[\\.]([A-Za-z]{2,4})$";
```

the way it works is - it allows OPTIONAL characters, then an optional apostrophe, then non-optional characters.

only downside is you cannot have a ' right before @ (also at least 2 characters after apostrophe) this can be tweaked more but i dont really see any point at all

Comment: Is this a modified regex or another regex entirely? If it's just been modified slightly, it'd be good if you could include what you have changed.

Comment: it is a modified regex. it has optional characters + optional apostrophe + characters. only downside is you cannot have a ' right before @ (also at least 2 characters after apostrophe) this can be tweaked more but i dont really see any point at all

Comment: Yeah, might be a good idea to put that in your answer to make it more clear.